# What is an alternative for "document.images"

Tags: javascript, html

I have a piece of code that manipulates images within a table by the document.images method like so:

```
document.images[myArray].src="imageZero.gif"
```

The code does exactly what I want however if I have other images on the page then this code affects them.

How do I change the code so it would only affect images within the table?

Regards,

jmcall10

Comment: Please provide your HTML and which image(s) you want to target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getElementsByTagName`:

First identify the table. If your table has an `id` attribute, then you can do this:

```
var mytable = document.getElementById('mytable');
```

Then call `getElementsByTagName`:

```
var images = mytable.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

Now you can use your index to access those images:

```
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].src = "imageZero.gif";
}
```

In modern browsers you can do this quicker with

```
for (const img of document.querySelectorAll('#mytable img')) {
    img.src = "imageZero.gif";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)('[css-selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors)')

So you want to target all images in one table you could so something like

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('table img');
```

if your table as an `ID` or a `class` and your images also the selector could look something like:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('table#tabl-id.tableclass img.class');
```

Make sure to follow and read BOTH links given at the top of this answer.

Now to change the `src` of your images as you did before like so:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('table img');
for(var i=0; i <= images.length; i++) {
    images[i].src="imageZero.gif"
}
```